# Matching author and title with elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to match books based on an author and title. Unfortunately titles and authors used as input differ from those in elasticsearch, the words are in different orders and have other differences so I can't do exact matching. My book records have a field author and title. I've come up with the following query:

```
{
  "query":{
    "bool":{
      "must":{
        "query_string":{
          "query":"Not the Israel My Parents Promised Me"
        },
        "fuzzy":{
          "author":{
            "value":"Peka, Harvey",
            "boost":2
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "from":1,
  "size":1
}
```

It's giving the same result every time no matter what the input so it seems like there's a problem with it. Am I going about it the wrong way?

Comment: What result is it giving? And what result would you like it to give? I see already a couple of things but would some more information. You're querying the `_all` field with the query_string, probably not what you want. Also, stick to the match query, usually better than query_string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I indexed some books and authors and tried this out. Worked for me for different combinatios, like, jumbled words and incomplete names and even when some words were incorrect, as shown below:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "default_field": "book",
            "query": "The girl with the angel tattoo"
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "default_field": "author",
            "query": "Steig Larsson"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks draxxeus, I didn't realize I could change the syntax to have two query_string's.

Comment: You could use a match query instead of a query_string to do the same, it's much safer.